# JAXB Vs JDOM : is it possible to update xml file using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i have been used JDOM to perform xml data entry & updation in any XML file, but now i am trying to use JAXB instead of JDOM but getting some difficulties.

as i know marshalling & unmarshalling in jaxb but when it comes to entry a new data into a xml at specified location (`node`), i find difficulties. e.g. `for new entry  Japan where id = Asia`

```
<file>
   <parent>
       <node id="Asia">
           <name>India</name>
           <name>China</name>
       </node>
       <node id="Europe">
          <name>UK</name>
       </node>
    </parent>
</file>
```

is there anybody who has idea about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken JAXB and JDOM and completely different things. JAXB will serialize java objects into an XML format and vice versa. JDOM simply reads in the XML file and stores it in a DOM tree which can then be used to modify the xml itself.

Using JAXB in this way is like trying to at runtime add a new variable to a class. It cannot be done. (at least to my knowledge).

Comment: oh, i do not have much idea but i am trying to unmarshal( `read xml file & convert it to java object`) & adding the new object at runtime and finally marshall to xml file, but i think you are right that is why i am not able to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @ExtremeCoder - In some respects JAXB and JDOM are similar since they both read XML into an in memory representation.  You can think of the JAXB model as a typed DOM, and the JDOM model as an untyped DOM.  Since JDOM is untyped you can easily add whatever node you want, but JAXB has no problems adding new data that corresponds to mapped fields/properties and types.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: i wanted to know, is it efficient to use JAXB for the new entry of data in xml file or should i use JDOM? I know the data can be added with Jaxb & JDOm but which one is better choice?

Comment: If you're using java objects as your data entries then JAXB is built for what your asking :)

Comment: @ExtremeCoder: this is where i am confused, data is send by user and it's up to me to design the application. as i have both the option to use either data as java Object or as raw data.

Comment: Only convert it to a java object if it actually is a java object or would be meaningful as a java object. Otherwise if you're just manipulating it go with JDOM only approach.

Comment: Ok, i got it.  Thanks ExtremeCoder